# Scroll image on hover - same speed for different image heights

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an image gallery with screenshots of different webpages. I want the preview window to be the same and the image to scroll with even speed. I managed to make it work, but can't fix the speed which differs depending on the image height.
Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-scroll-wrapper">
  <img class="image-scroll" src="[image_url]">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-scroll-wrapper {
   height: 250px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.image-scroll {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   transition: top 5s ease-out 0s;
}
.image-scroll:hover {
   transform: translate(0, calc( -100% + 250px ));
   transition: 5s ease!important;
}
```

This makes longer images scroll faster (obviously). I also tried `top: -1000px!important;` for the `:hover` option instead of the `translate` - but this makes shorter images scroll more than their height.

I'm sure this can be done via JS. Any recommendations?

Comment: This is not possible with just CSS, you would need to use JS. Related questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713882/how-to-make-a-css-animation-transition-play-at-a-fixed-speed-not-a-fixed-durati) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711237/set-css-transition-to-use-speed-instead-of-duration)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to set the css transition time with javscript according to the height of the image. This way you can use the native css transition property and avoid a bunch of extra javascript.

In the example below for demonstration purposes I am placing boxes in the scrolling container so you can see the effect but the scroller div would be your image in your example.  As you can see I have boxes in each of the scrolling divs all set to the same height.  There are three in the first scrolling div and five in the second scrolling div so the scrolling divs are different heights but as you can see they scroll at the same speed.

Note if you want the speed to be exactly the same you need to use a linear ease value.  I have this set in the javascript.  If you want to use ease-out there will be a little bit of difference in speed because of the easing but I think it will be negligible in real world applications.  If you want to use different easing besides linear you can change linear to ease-out in the javascript if you like. The speed is dependent on the pxPerSec value.  Obviously a higher number will result in faster speeds.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.scroller');
const pxPerSec = 150;

const setStyle = (el) => {
  const height = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  // 250 is the height of the wrapper element
  const distance = height - 250;
  const ms = (distance / pxPerSec) * 1000;
  el.style.transition = `transform ${ms}ms linear`;
};

elements.forEach((el) => setStyle(el));

//Just for demo purposes
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

/* .scroller.active is just for demo purposes */
.scroller.active,
.wrapper:hover .scroller {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 250px));
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* Just for demo purposes */
.demo-box {
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-box">Hover on box or <button>Click Me</button></div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```